# Right way to modify JhiAlertService in ng-jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I currently use the following version of jhipster generator:

**"ng-jhipster": "0.2.6".**

I want to modify **JhiAlertService** to make it compatible with **snackBar (angular material)**. I have noticed that **NotificationInterceptor** invokes the **JhiAlertService**:

```
this.alertService = injector.get (JhiAlertService));
```

My question is that **JhiAlertService** belongs to jhipster, so what is the recommended way:

1._ Make a fork of the **ng-jhipster 0.2.6** repository and do the direct modification on this fork, then add the fork to my package.json, I'm not sure how to make this inclusion.

2._ Create a new ***JhiMyAlertService*** Service and include it by injection in **NotificationInterceptor**?

Currently I have directly modified JhiAlertService to test my changes and I got the operation I wanted, but obviously when downloading my changes from the repository this change of mine will not be. So, what would be the right way, any suggestions?

original file without changes.
https://github.com/Hizmarck/ng-jhipster/tree/master/src/service

Greetings.